# PDF: Erroneous cross-reference stream accepted by applications

Tags: pdf

Annotating in Drawboard PDF, it generated this strange cross-reference stream (unless I have misunderstood, I would say incorrect):

```
/W = [1, 2, 0]
Data = [2, 1, 183, 248, 2, 0, 1, 88, 2, 0, 3, 245, 2, 0, 0, 21, 2, 0, 2, 7]
```

From the reference:

> A value of zero for an element in the W array indicates that the
>   corresponding field is not present in the stream, and the default
>   value is used, if there is one.

Each entry in the data should have 1 + 2 + 0 = 3 bytes but clearly this is not true - there are 5 entries with 4 bytes. No application I tried has problems opening the file, but I don't know how to deal with this in my PDF library.

Comment: Any chance to see the original PDF document?

Comment: [Original](https://github.com/pdf-rs/pdf/blob/dev/tests/files/xelatex.pdf) - [Annotated](https://github.com/pdf-rs/pdf/files/977665/xelatex_drawboard.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the first byte of each 4 byte groups is 2, I assume that your data has prediction applied to it. After decompression, if you apply the predictor, you will get 5 groups of 3 bytes.

**Update**: As I correctly assumed, the xref stream uses a predictor to improve compression (this is just a sample xref stream in your file as all the others follow the same pattern):

```
92 0 obj
<<
  /DecodeParms <</Columns 3/Predictor 12>>
  /Filter /FlateDecode
  /ID [<1EBBF34ADD340749DCDB9CA0F9F0F8F8> <1EBBF34ADD340749DCDB9CA0F9F0F8F8>]
  /Index [48 1 89 4]
  /Info 2 0 R
  /Length 28
  /Prev 46782
  /Root 1 0 R
  /Size 93
  /Type /XRef
  /W [1 2 0]>>
stream
  xœcbÜþƒ‰1‚‰ù+ƒ(; +ª*
endstream
endobj
```

After decompression you have 5 groups of 4 bytes. You have to apply the predictor otherwise the decompressed data is invalid. After applying the predictor you will get 5 groups of 3 bytes.
There is no error here regarding PDF libraries.

Comment: I assume you mean 5 groups of 4 bytes, as there are 20 bytes in total. I didn't use a predictor, but that could be done indeed. It surprises me that PDF libraries go to such extent to be forgiving of errors. But you are probably right that that's indeed what happens.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by predictor. Now I understand, thanks. If I may ask a follow-up question here: in the PDF 1.7 ref, page 75: "the specific predictor function used is explicitly encoded in the incoming data", without any further information - what does this mean?

Comment: @Ploppz - When /Predictor is greater than or equal to 10 the actual predictor code in encoded in the data in the first byte of each row. In your scenario you have 5 groups of 4 bytes. First byte is the predictor, next 3 are data.

Comment: I just came back to this. If I may ask regarding the decoded but not PNG-unfiltered data that I provided in the question ([2, 1, 183, 248 ...]): It's not clear to me from the PDF 1.7 ref, whether the first value of each row is 1 for no prediction, 2 for TIFF predictor, and 10-15 for PNG prediction - or just 0-5 for different PNG predictors. The algorithm I wrote treats the '2' as meaning 'Up' predictor - is this correct?

Comment: @Ploppz - from PDF spec: "For LZWDecode and FlateDecode, a Predictor value greater than or equal to 10 merely indicates that a PNG predictor is in use; the specific predictor function used is explicitly encoded in the incoming data." - /Predictor values 1 & 2 are not included in data. For PNG /Predictor 10 to 15 the predictor codes 0-5 are included at the beginning of each row.